# VBA Excel define range selection by button location

Tags: excel, vba

I have the buttons with the same macro assigned.

The macro picks up always the same range

[image]

which is selected here.

In the code it looks liek this:

```
 Dim asbrng As Range
 Set asbrng = tw.Range("M15:P41")
 asbrng.Copy
```

It looks like I have to dulicate my macros by the number of buttons and change the range of cells.

It could be accordingly for the second button:

```
 tw.Range("R15:U41")
```

for the third

```
tw.Range("W15:Z41") and so forth
```

for another ones beneath

```
tw.Range("M44:P70")
```

etc.

Is there any option of using the same macro, which would pick up the cells located just above the button? Could it be by defining the offset range from the button or something like this?

Comment: You have a click event per button. The easiest way is possibly to shorten your code to `tw.Range("M15:P41").copy` and adjust the range accordingly per button.
If you want to go fancy you would create a [control array](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/vba-control-arrays.htm) but that could be too much for three or four buttons only.

Comment: I can adjust the range per button, but I will be obligated to create a separate macro for it. Am I right? I mean the whole coding will be the same apart from this range of selection only.

Comment: Yes, you will have a click event per button and one line of code per button. As said, in case of three or four buttons I wouldn't worry.  Otherwise you could go for a control array (see link above) or you create an extra single sub which takes a range a input.

Comment: Please add neccessary details like "How many buttons?" "Which kind of button?" etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923823/using-one-sub-for-multiple-buttons-in-excel-vba/37924540#comment63298139_37923823

Comment: What type of buttons do you use? ActiveX or Form buttons?

Comment: And which ar the buttons (in the shown picture)? The blue ones having as caption "BUILD COMPLETE PHOTO"?

Comment: No, the buttons are beneath with the "GENERATE" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reference a Range Dependent on Which Button Was Pressed

[image]

```vb
Sub RefRangeByButton()
    
    Const RANGE_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 27
    Const RANGE_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 4
    Const BUTTON_ROW_OFFSET As Long = -27
    Const BUTTON_COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 0
    
    Dim CallerName As Variant: CallerName = Application.Caller
    If IsError(CallerName) Then
        MsgBox "This code has to be run from a button!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim btn As Button:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set btn = ws.Buttons(CallerName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If btn Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no button named """ & CallerName _
            & """ on worksheet """ & ws.Name & """!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = btn.TopLeftCell _
        .Offset(BUTTON_ROW_OFFSET, BUTTON_COLUMN_OFFSET) _
        .Resize(RANGE_ROWS_COUNT, RANGE_COLUMNS_COUNT)
        
    MsgBox "I'm a button and my name is """ & CallerName & """." & vbLf _
        & "My top-left cell is """ & btn.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0) & """." _
        & vbLf & vbLf & "By pressing me, you have referenced the range """ _
        & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ on worksheet """ & ws.Name & """!", _
        vbInformation
        
    ' Continue, e.g.:
    'rg.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I assign it to the existing macro? It seems like I have to create a new macro for it right?

Comment: Copy this sub to a standard module. Rename it appropriately. Then assign it to all buttons. Run it using each button and verify if the range is correct. If not, move the cell or change the constants until it is. After that add your previous code that will use `rg` as the range. Hard to help when you don't post your code.

Comment: Found another way by using the Call command. Anyway, no error is shown as it seems to work. The problem is, that nothing is picked up from the considered area. The offset stuff seems to be wrong. It doesn't select the area at all.

Comment: I see, at the line (from linked macro) where I have:  Set asbrng = Selection  I get an error: Expected function or variable